# Proving that the $C_b(M)$ is a complete space with the $L^{\infty}$ norm.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $A$ is some metric space, and let us define $C_b(M)$ as the vector space consisting of the set of all bounded continuous $\mathbb{R}$ valued functions on $A$. Now, we define the $L^{\infty}$ norm as:

$||g|| =$ sup$\{|g(x)|:x\in A\}$

I am trying to prove that $C_b(M)$ is a complete metric space when equipped with the $L^{\infty}$ norm.

So far I have tried to do a proof by contradiction but I suspect that there might be some constructive or inductive argument involved. I would greatly appreciate any insights!

Answer (score 1):

To show it's complete you have to show that every Cauchy sequence of such functions converges. The Cauchy condition with respect to the sup norm (i.e., the $L^\infty$ norm) is precisely uniform convergence. A well-known theorem states that a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions does converge to a continuous function. QED.